# Using java code instead of hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am trying to use hibernate in our project to load data from tables. 
I did set up of adding hibernate jars, then added hibernate.cfg.xml and the BO class of table. 
But our product code sees a xml file and validates against it. It fails because this xml is not accordance standard. 
So i am trying to load this file using java code. 
While building the session factory, i did 
Configuration config=new Configuration().configure();
But at run time this again fails as it is expecting the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Can we write completely java code without needing xml or property file. 
I cannot use xml file for sure, but if i have to use property file using java code, please suggest how to do it.

Comment: You may want to try JooQ instead of hibernate...

Comment: Why is your product code accessing that XML file anyway?

Comment: It detects all the xml files in the source code and then generates artifacts from them. But now i have deleted the xml file and only java code is there.